# changing mutable state value in component

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

i have a component (slider) with a float value and wanna change the value of it with plus and mines button in another component (changeSliderValue),
i want to:

1. create the changeSliderValue only when slider component is selected and change the value of slider when the floatValue in the changeSliderValue is changed.
2. fix the changeSliderValue UI component position in the bottom right corner when it's created.

my main component is :

```
@composable
fun slider(text: String, value: Float) {

    var value: Float by remember {
        mutableStateOf(value)
    }
    var selected: Boolean by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    val backgroundColor: Color = when (selected) {
        true -> Color(24, 45, 122)
        false -> Color.Transparent
    }
    val fontColor: Color = when (selected) {
        true -> Color.White
        false -> Color(143, 143, 143)
    }
    value = when (selected){
       true -> changeSliderValue(value = value)
        false -> value
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(108.dp)
            .height(60.dp)
            .background(backgroundColor, shape = RoundedCornerShape(16))
            .padding(5.dp),
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
                Text(text = text)
            }
            Text(
                text = value.toString(),
                fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(R.font.sevensegment)),
                color = fontColor,
                fontSize = 20.sp
            )

        }
    }


}
```

and my second component is :

```
@Composable
fun changeSliderValue(value: Float): Float {

    var floatValue:Float by remember{
        mutableStateOf(value)
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(227.dp)
            .height(58.dp)
            .background(color = Color(19, 36, 98), shape = RoundedCornerShape(20))
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalAlignment =Alignment.CenterVertically ,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(17.dp , alignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        ) {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(20))
                    .width(48.dp)
                    .height(48.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        floatValue -= 0.1F
                    },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.minus),
                    contentDescription = null,

                    tint = Color(19, 36, 98)
                )
            }
            CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl) {
                Text(
                    text = "افزایش/کاهش",
                    color = Color.White
                )
            }
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .background(Color.White, shape = RoundedCornerShape(20))
                    .width(48.dp)
                    .height(48.dp)
                    .clickable { floatValue += 0.1F },
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center

            ) {
                Icon(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.plus),
                    contentDescription = null,

                    tint = Color(19, 36, 98)
                )
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetpack Compose follows the [unidirectional data flow (UDF) pattern](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/architecture#udf). This means that data flows downwards the Composable hierarchy and changes/events are communicated to the parent Composables using callbacks.

I'm not totally sure what you are trying to achieve, but I think there are some predefined Composables that you could use.
Especially check out the [Slider Composable](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#slider) and the [OutlinedButton Composable](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/components/button#outlined_button).

Also have a look at the [Icons library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/icons/Icons) that comes as part of the Jetpack Compose framework. It allows you to use a wide range of icons without needing to copy it into your project manually. You can get it by adding the following dependency to your module's `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
```

A solution then could look like this:

```
@Composable
fun SliderComposable() {

    var value by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(50f) }
    
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly
    ) {
        OutlinedButton(onClick = { value--; value.coerceIn(0f, 100f) },
            modifier = Modifier.size(50.dp),
            enabled = value != 0, 
            shape = CircleShape,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Minus, contentDescription = "content description")
        }
        
        // Use the predefined Jetpack Compose Slider Composable
        Slider(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            enabled = true,
            value = value,
            onValueChange = { value = it },
            valueRange = 0f..100f,
            steps = 1
        )
        
        OutlinedButton(onClick = { value++; value.coerceIn(0f, 100f) },
            modifier= Modifier.size(50.dp),
            enabled = value != 100,
            shape = CircleShape,
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(0.dp)
        ) {
            Icon(Icons.Default.Plus, contentDescription = "content description")
        }
    }
}
```

This will result in a Slider ranging from 0 to 100 with a minus button on its left and a plus button on its right. Dragging the Slider updates the value, and pressing the buttons updates the value displayed in the Slider. I hope this is enough to get you started.

Comment: i handled the dataflow with adding onchangeValue to the function and about icons, the designer already given them to me and i imported all of them as drawable, but thanks for the advice.